# Watch in Vue.js 3 setup

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, watch

I've to change my current Vue.js code to Vue.js 3 <script setup> code, but I've problem with  the `watch` property. What is proper syntax for `watch` in `<script setup>`?

Current code:

```
  watch: {
    config: {
      handler(newConfig) {
        if (this.$refs && this.$refs.range && this.$refs.range.noUiSlider) {
          this.$refs.range.noUiSlider.destroy()
          const newSlider = this.noUiSliderInit(newConfig)
          return newSlider
        }
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  }
```

How should it look like in `<script setup>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vue.js is known for its excellent documentation - [Watchers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#basic-example) (make sure you select composition API).

Basically:

```
import {watch} from "vue";
//
//
//
watch(config, (newConfig) => {
    // Your code
}, { deep: true });
```

Obviously, "Your code" will be different **to** what you currently have, but I assume you only needed help with how to use `watch`.

i.e., all the `this.*` is obviously different in composition API (where you never use `this`).

It's worth noting that *When you call watch() directly on a reactive object, it will implicitly create a deep watcher - the callback will be triggered on all nested mutations:* [Deep Watchers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers)

So, you may not even need the `deep:true` option - of course with such a small code fragment in the question, it's hard to say what `config` is.

Comment: Hey, I was looking all over for how to use deep watch in the script setup, there are no examples on how to do this in the documentation. I'd like to ask, how did you figure out the syntasx that allowed you to put options in the watch?

Comment: @Joeygr - did you read the linked *documentation*

Comment: Apparently I did not. I was doing a coding challenge where I had a blindfold on, so I'm sure you'd understand me not noticing that.

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this.

```
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      newSlider
    }
  },
  watch: {
    config: {
  handler(newConfig) {
    if (this.$refs && this.$refs.range && this.$refs.range.noUiSlider) {
      this.$refs.range.noUiSlider.destroy()
      const newSlider = this.noUiSliderInit(newConfig)
    }
  },
  deep: true,
},
  }
})
```

Comment: I've to do this in <script setup> syntax

Comment: it need to   import {  watch} from "vue" and it is <script setup